# Can not display the list and h1 tag on the same line

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make a webpage with the menu list and the logo side by side. In the code below whenever I try to make them side by side one of them moves down on the page.I want both the list and the heading side by side.Here is the code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-UK"> 
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Fahad | Just another web designer</title>
        <!--Styling Starts-->
    </script> 
       <style type="text/css"> 
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy&v1' rel='stylesheet'               type='text/css'>
            h1 { font-family: 'Chewy', arial, serif;
             }
             h1 {
                 font-size:45px; 
                 padding-top:70px;
                 padding-left:350px;
             }
            .menu 
            {
                padding:0;
                margin-left:0;  
                height:200px;
                width:300px;
            }
              .menu ul
             {
                padding-left:200px;
                padding-top:45px;
                font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
                list-style-type:none;
                text-decoration:none;
                color:#666;
              }
              .container
              {
                color:#666; 
              }
              a:link
              {
                 color:#666;
              }
              a:hover
              {
                 color:#333;
              }
              a:active
              {
                color:#666;
              }

     </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
       <h1>Fahad</h1>  
            <div class="menu">

            <ul>
                <li><a>Home</a> </li>    
                <li><a>Blog</a></li>
                <li><a>About</a></li>
                <li><a>Contact</a></li> 

            </ul>

            </div><!--logo div ends-->

        </div><!--Container Div ends-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: You should read the [CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/), this is basic stuff...

Comment: Short answer: Either `display:inline-block` or `float:left`

Comment: I tried both of them. I was still unable to get both the menu and heading in the same line.

Comment: You're trying to position your elements with padding - this won't work. Here's how it's done: http://jsfiddle.net/YKcf7/

Comment: Thanks that works fine.Please post this as answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make two (or more) sibling elements appear in one line, you can use the `inline-block` value. Just apply `display:inline-block` to those elements.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/DcS4u/

Comment: What if I want to break the page into three divisions? I used float left and right to get two divisions. I have also seen more than two. Can you give a hint how?

Comment: @Just Assuming that the three divisions are represented by DIV's that are siblings, just `float:left` all three DIV's. Also assign `width` values to those DIV's. The parent element (the wrapper) should have `overflow:auto` set.

Answer (score 2):

H1 and LI by default are block elements.  If you want to have them live on the same line as another element you have to change it to inline.

```
H1, LI
{
  display: inline;
}
```

However, that may cause you more harm than good.
You should look into [floating](http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/) block elements on the same line.

***Updated:***

Similarly, you can get 3 containers to float:

```
<div class="floater-parent clearfix">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
</div>

.floater-parent DIV
{
   width: 150px;
   float: left;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to break the page into three divisions? I used float left and right to get two divisions. I have also seen more than two. Can you give a hint how?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `float: left` to the h1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first float both the h1 and the menu left

```
h1, .menu {float:left;}
```

and then to make sure the any content which comes after the menu doesn't display on the same line, you need to clear on the very next sibling element.

```
example: #pageContent {clear:both;} // technically this could be clear:left.

<body>
  <h1>My Page</h1>
  <div class="menu">link1, link2</div>
  <div id="pageContent">
    Contents of my page
  </div>
</body>
```